# How do I find what is making my laptop hibernate at low battery?

Tags: windows, laptop, battery, hibernate

This seems like an obvious question but it's more convoluted than it appears.  At 7.5% my laptop goes into hibernate (which is about 40 minutes of power left).  I have changed all the power plans to 1% as well as searching for anything else that might be overriding my selected power management settings (e.g. Battery Bar) and changing those.  Nothing changes the outcome.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
HP Spectre x360, Windows 10.
Thanks

Comment: From @S.Beasley: Have you tried resetting your power settings to default? It could be that someone tampered with them. You could do this through command prompt.  You could also download Microsoft's power troubleshooter. There's one for Win 8, but I'm sure there's one for Windows 10 by now.

Comment: Have you looked through all of the HP software installed on the system? It could be a utility bundled with your system that is acting independently of Windows' power management features.

Answer (score 1):

Admin command prompt

powercfg /x hibernate-timeout-dc 10

The 10 is 10 minutes